# Can We Use Conditionals Inside Embedded Questions Inside Participle Phrases?

Tags: conditional-constructions, participle-phrases, embedded-clauses

This question sounds more complex than it is, so I'll provide the piece of writing that made me curious:

> These realities differ from the core MCU in both minor and substantial ways, showing what would've happened if the films had played out differently.

Basically, I'm curious about the use of an 'if' subordinate clause inside a participle phrase. Is this considered part of the wh-clause (noun clause)? Or is this a subordinate clause inside a participle phrase, which would surely make it not a phrase anymore? I'm almost certain it's a part of the noun clause, but I would like clarification for peace of mind.

Comment: You *could* say that "showing" is the first word of a participle phrase. OR you could say that "what would've happened" is a wh-clause / noun clause. I don't really see how either perspective helps or hinders understanding. But what I *would* say is the actual ***if-*** clause obviously modifies the *second* of those entities (it doesn't make much sense to assume the act of "showing" could somehow be "conditional" on the counterfactual possibility of the films playing out differently).

Comment: I should also add that my thinking stems from the knowledge that wh-clauses can often be expanded to relative clauses (e.g. 'the thing that' instead of 'what'). However, that's irrelevant now that I think about it, as the conditional would still reside inside an adjective clause that modifies the noun 'the thing' (not affecting the participle phrase). Basically, I think my question should be 'Can subordinate clauses exist inside subordinate clauses when they fulfill a specific grammatical function (such as a noun or adjective clause)?'

Comment: *this is the cat that killed the rat that ate the corn...* I think that's the traditional way of showing that English can recursively nest as many relative clauses as you like. And although I'm not big on grammatical terminology, it seems to me that in the current context, "relative clause" and "subordinate clause" mean pretty much the same thing.

Comment: ...so long as we introduce the ***if-*** clause immediately after ***that*** in my example, we seem to be able to continue nesting: *this is the cat that **if it was hungry** killed the rat that ate the corn...* But if the ***if-*** clause comes at the ***end*** of the ***that-*** clause, this  seems to rule out any further nesting: *this is the cat that killed the rat **if it was hungry*** can't be extended.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is basically what I thought, but it's good to hear it from someone else. By the way, if you're interested, since you said you're not big on grammatical terms, a relative clause is another word for an adjective clause. So it's not interchangeable with a subordinate clause, although it is a type of subordinate clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having developed my understanding of grammar, I am prepared to answer my own question. Yes, we can use conditionals inside embedded questions that reside in participle phrases. This is called '[embedding](https://www.thoughtco.com/embedding-grammar-1690643)' or 'nesting,' which means that this conditional (a subordinate clause) becomes part of the embedded question (a noun clause). In the example I gave, the embedded question is acting as an object of the verb 'showing.' As such, it doesn't change the fact that 'showing' (a present participle) introduces a participle phrase, as it has no subject by itself.